# Serialize a container of enums as strings using JSON.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

You can serialize an enum field in an WebAPI model as a string by adding an attribute:

```
enum Size
{
    Small,
    Medium,
    Large
}

class Example1
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]
    Size Size { get; set; }
}
```

This will serialize to this JSON:

```
{
  "Size": "Medium"
}
```

How can I accomplish the same for a collections of enums?

```
class Example2
{
    IList<Size> Sizes { get; set; }
}
```

I want to serialize to this JSON:

```
{
  "Sizes":
  [
    "Medium",
    "Large"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You need to use [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) property:

```
class Example2
{
    [JsonProperty (ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public IList<Size> Sizes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So how to actually populate `Sizes`?

Comment: Thank you so much, been stuck on this for a day and a half

Comment: how could I do that with `[EnumMember(Value = "?")] EMPTY = '?'`, so that my model (for `[FromBody]`) can reflect json with a property that is an array like: `[ 'X', '?', 'X' ]`, yielding: `[ MyEnum.X, MyEnum.EMPTY, MyEnum.X ]`?

Answer (score 15):

I have this in the startup code of my web app to serialise all enums to strings (I prefer passing enum names to values, makes things more robust).

Must admit I've never tried it on a list of enums though so I don't know what it would do with that - might be worth a try.

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = true });
```

Comment: I can confirm this works for a list of enums. My ideal solution would allow opt-in on a per-property basis, but this works and it's better than nothing. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon-Eric Athari's solution also works and will give you the per-property opt-in you are looking for.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work for Dictionary<int,SomeEnum> though :/