# How to use JsonConverterAttribute with array/list

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I would like to decorate a list or an array in a class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute for the inner type.  For example...

```
public class Record
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(UnixDateTimeConverter))]    // This works
    public DateTime SingleDate { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(UnixDateTimeConverter))]    // This doesn't work
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> DateList { get; set; }
}
```

I do *not* want to:

- Write a converter for `IList<DateTime>` or similar
- Register the converter in the `JsonSerializerSettings`

I would like to accomplish this using decorators on the target class alone if possible.

Simple fiddle containing example code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/b0dves

Comment: use [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) as shown in [Serialize a container of enums as strings using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647073/3744182).  Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AiykDw

Comment: @dbc that should be an answer!