# Custom JsonConverter - ReadJson is never get called

Tags: c#, json.net

My Dto object's property looks like below, where PaymentGatewayType is an Enum. I need to implement a custom deserialization to reflect the list of string representation of the PaymentGatewayType.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(PaymentGatewayTypeConverter))]
public List<PaymentGatewayType> AvailablePaymentGateway { get; set; }
```

Here is the deserialization point

```
restaurantSettings.AvailablePaymentGateway = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PaymentGatewayType>>("['PayPal', 'Stripe']");
```

Here is the Enum

```
public enum PaymentGatewayType
{
    PayPal = 1,
    Stripe = 2
}
```

However, in my PaymentGatewayTypeConverter, ReadJson is never get called. Always the WriteJson is get called.

(I have read almost all of the relevant QnAs in the stackoverflow, regarding this issue and those have not helped me or not precise enough)

**Edit :**
Here is the reproducible sample : https://dotnetfiddle.net/zm72E6

Comment: Is `PaymentGatewayTypeConverter` for an individual `PaymentGatewayType` or for the entire list?  If for an individual `PaymentGatewayType` you need to use [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647073/3744182) to [Serialize a container of enums as strings using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18640162/3744182).  If for the list we need to see a [mcve] to help you.

Comment: This is for the List of enum. Please find the reproducible sample here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/zm72E6

Comment: Mark your `AvailablePaymentGateway` property with `[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` instead of `[JsonConverter(...)]`  This will fix the problem.  See fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eOzCDy).  I am marking this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Mahi Glad I could help.