# How to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject into a type that is an Interface

Tags: c#, json.net

My code:

```
var configuration = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IConfigurationService>(json));
```

fails at run-time with the error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Could not create an instance of type .....IConfigurationService. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'MyProperty', line 2, position 25.'

If I replace the IConfigurationService with the concrete version (that implements IConfigurationService) like so:

```
var configuration = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigurationService>(json));
```

It works fine.  But that defeats the object of using an interface.  How can I get the deserialise to work with the interface?

Assume IConfigurationService is this simple:

```
public interface IConfigurationService
{
    string MyProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

I have looked on the Web and it seems I need to use a **JsonConverter**, however all of the examples relate to MyProperty being an Interface.

Comment: One way or another you need to specify the concrete class to instantiate.  The standard solution is to use a subclass of `CustomCreationConverter<T>`.  See e.g. [NewtonSoft.Json Serialize and Deserialize class with property of type `IEnumerable<ISomeInterface>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11754633/3744182).  The solution applies equally whether the interface is the *root type* or some *nested type*.

Comment: Does that answer work for you, or do you still have a problem?  If you still have a problem, can you explain what it is?

Comment: An interface can't exist in a vacuum - it simply describes a behavior, a contract. Something must be there to implement it, and that something must be chosen when you deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

I decided I did not need the interface.  I just used the concrete class.  Thank you for all of the help.