# How I can deserialize object contain abstract class property using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, json.net

I need to convert a json string to an object of type `FullArticle`; the  `ArticleBody` (property in `FullArticle` class) is an abstract class.

How can I deserialize it into a concrete class? I know already is HtmlBody implemented `ArticleBody`.

```
public class FullArticle : ArticleListItem
{
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    // ToDo Check this for removal
    public bool IsDone { get; private set; }

    public ArticleBody Body { get; }

    public long ViewCount { get; }
    public string Keywords { get; }
}
```

Comment: you can map it to a DTO containing only the properties you want, 
plus its not recommended to cast your public domain models through public APIs 
my best thought on this is yo create a DTO

Comment: Assuming you want **always** `ArticleBody` to be deserialized as `HtmlBody`, create `ArticleBodyConverter` as a subclass of [`CustomCreationConverter<ArticleBody>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCustomCreationConverter.htm) and override `public override ArticleBody Create(Type objectType) => new HtmlBody()` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11761508/3744182) to [NewtonSoft.Json Serialize and Deserialize class with property of type IEnumerable<ISomeInterface>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11754633/3744182).  In fact I think this is a duplicate, agree?

Comment: If not a duplicate please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] that includes (possibly simplified) versions of JSON, `ArticleBody` and `HtmlBody` that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Or if your `ArticleBody` might actually be polymorphic, see [How to call JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and disable a JsonConverter applied to a base type via `[JsonConverter]`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45547123/3744182) and [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182).  We need to see a [mcve] to be sure one way or the other.